# How to prevent objects inside a collection from contributing to the scene statistics

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, collections

I always have multiple collections but always one for Scale References. In Scale References collection I have multiple real-world-scaled objects that I am always visually comparing with, but of course they are always counted on Statistics panel and I am always confused of how many polygons my object have, it is further important for me as of I am a Game Artist.

Is there any way to hide Collections for Statistics?

Comment: If you hide or exclude the collection from the current view layer, the polygons shouldn't be counted in the statistics, but I don't think there is a way to prevent it if you need the items to be visible at all times